# Escape forward slash

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using this code for case insensitive searching:

```
Effect.find({name: new RegExp('^'+name+'$', "i")}).lean().exec(function(err, effect){
    if(err) return callback(err, null);
    callback(null, effect);
});
```

At first look it looked like it works fine.

**Problem:**

I have an effect called `test A/c`.

When I search for an exact case insensitive match in the database, I get wiered results:

**Case:1** When I search for `test A/`, I get a match found.

**Case:2** Also for `test A/c`, I get a match found.

Which is not right for the first case. I know that is a problem with my Regex expression. But I am fairly new to Regex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At last found the mistake. `new RegExp()` function does not need to escape `backslash`. My mistake was, I was sending this value from url and thus it was counted as new parameter after slash.