# Combine two regex patterns: case insensitivity and escape backslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that I can use case insensitive approach as follows:

```
var name = "test A/c";
{name: new RegExp('^'+name+'$', "i")}
```

Now I want to escape backslash in above expression. I know how to escape backslash:

```
/\//ig;
```

But I dont know how to use these two patterns in combination with each other.

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the backslash in the first expression that you want to escape?

Comment: Is this Javascript?

Comment: @KernelPanic Yes its Javascript.

Comment: `A/c` has a forward slash not backward slash and it doesn't require escaping while using `RegExp` object

Comment: @anubhava Please take a look at this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680530/escape-forward-slash

Comment: @anubhava At last found the mistake. new RegExp() function does not need to escape backslash. My mistake was, I was sending this value from url and thus it was counted as new parameter after slash. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace in second expression.

`var name = "test A/c";`
`{name: new RegExp('^'+name.replace(/\//g,'\\/')+'$', "i")}`

Comment: No, still getting the same results after trying to replace as you said.

Comment: Please take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680530/escape-forward-slash

Comment: I am on mobile. I will check it in an hour.

Comment: That also doesn't make any difference.

Comment: At last found the mistake. new RegExp() function does not need to escape backslash. My mistake was, I was sending this value from url and thus it was counted as new parameter after slash. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using the following way ...

```
var name = "test A/c".replace(/(?=\/)/g, '\\\\');
{name: new RegExp('^'+name+'$', "ig")}
```

Comment: I have given the example here. But in reality, the value of variable name will be coming from database.

Comment: You should explain why the double slashes are necessary. `Teach a man to fish`...

Comment: still getting the same result. Please take a look at this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680530/escape-forward-slash

Comment: At last found the mistake. new RegExp() function does not need to escape backslash. My mistake was, I was sending this value from url and thus it was counted as new parameter after slash. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this post [Escaping Strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770523/escaping-strings-in-javascript) and check if this is what you are looking for.

quoting from above link:

`function addslashes( str ) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"']/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}`

Comment: Good job on citing relevant information, though thi is more of a comment. You should copy relevant text here. If that url is changed, the link becomes useless.

Comment: At last found the mistake. new RegExp() function does not need to escape backslash. My mistake was, I was sending this value from url and thus it was counted as new parameter after slash. Thank you for helping.